# How to translate a config file in Hugo?

Tags: translation, hugo

I'm using Hugo for the first time and I'm having troubles with translations.

More specifically, I'm using the [hugo-theme-bootstrap](https://github.com/razonyang/hugo-theme-bootstrap) theme. In `config\_default`, I have a file named `author.toml` that contains information like the author's name, bio, city, etc. It looks like this:

```
name = "Pascal Bergeron"
avatar = "images/profile.jpg"
bio = "Description française."
location = "Montréal"
```

The issue is that this file is used for both the English and French versions of my website. However, I need the `bio` and `location` fields to change according to the language. I've tried creating a file named `author.fr.toml`, but its settings end up being ignored. In fact, if I even rename `author.toml` to `author.en.toml`, the settings will be ignored for the English language. It's as if I can only have a `author.toml` file. This is strange because I can translate all other files in my `config` folder that way (I have a `params.en.toml` and a `params.fr.toml` file for instance).

I've done some digging in the `layouts` folder of my theme and I've found the file where the `author.toml` is used to create the HTML code. It looks like this:

```
{{- with .Site.Author -}}
<section class="profile surface row">
  <div class="col-xl-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <img class="profile-avatar img-fluid" src="{{ absURL (default "images/profile.webp" .avatar) }}" alt="{{ .name }}" loading="lazy">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6">
    <h5 class="profile-name my-2">{{ .name }}</h5>
    {{- with .bio -}}
    <div class="profile-bio mb-2">{{ . }}</div>
    {{- end -}}
    {{- with .company -}}
    <div class="profile-company mb-2"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-building"></i>{{ . }}</div>
    {{- end -}}
    {{- with .location -}}
    <div class="profile-location mb-2"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ . }}</div>
    {{- end -}}
    {{- if .about -}}
      <div class="profile-about mb-2"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i><a target="_blank" href="{{ .about }}">{{ i18n "about_me" }}</a></div>
    {{- else -}}
      {{- with $.GetPage "about" -}}
      <div class="profile-about mb-2"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i><a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a></div>
      {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
  </div>
</section>
{{- end -}}
```

How can I have a `author.toml` file for each language?

Comment: Hello Pascal, So, why are you using a toml file to describe an author? Ideally, if it's a language change, look, I don't know the structure of the site. But, ideally, if it's each language has it's own author or a page. Lets take a page, and you need an author tag to change, based on, guess what, who authored it. Well, fine, then in the template, have a .Param reference which references the author noted in the markdown, it then get's the (MARKDOWN) file which has all author data, by param or by .Content, and there you go. Just clarify a bit more what you are trying to do/solve and we'll help!

Comment: @Rogelio the question is: why does this work for params.en.toml and not for author.en.toml...? I frankly have no idea. Seems like a weird bug.

Comment: Okay - so the question is - why do you have an author.en.toml file? So Toml is used for enviroment specific issues (https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#configuration-file)... I checked that theme it seems to be only using params and config.toml which is correct (as far as I have experienced), so I assume you added this author.toml... What problem is the toml file trying to solve for you? With that I'm sure we can help you. For instance, if you are trying to have an author assigned by language to pages, that can be done, very easily, just let me know.

Comment: @Rogelio The author.toml is provided by the theme. The theme also provide language-specific files for files such as config.toml and params.toml. Thus, it was my understanding that I could have language-specific author.toml file too. See: https://github.com/razonyang/hugo-theme-bootstrap/tree/master/exampleSite/config/_default

Comment: @Rogelio Also, author.toml contains configuration info not for a page, but for a section in the sidebar. See the first box on the top right on https://hbs.razonyang.com/en/

Comment: Thanks @PascalBergeron, tracking on that and much appreciated for your answers.
https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(TLDR - The site author set-up the author data as 1 config file - i.e. Theme is built for 1 author for the entire site).

Hello Pascal, so, really appreciated you took the time to answer me.
To clarify:

1. This isn't a "hugo" thing, but the way this chap built this theme.
2. You are going to have to modify his theme (or reach out to him). The specific file in question, as you point out, I believe is profile.html in sidebar:

   {{- if .Site.Author -}}
   {{- $layout := default "" .Site.Author.params.layout -}}
   {{- if eq $layout "compact" -}}
   {{- partial "sidebar/profile/compact" . -}}
   {{- else -}}
   {{- partial "sidebar/profile/default" . -}}
   {{- end -}}
   {{- end -}}

If you follow the various partials this calls, i.e. down the rabbit whole you will find an example (this is one of many), like you describe and quote in your question, it has the specific comment {{ - with .Site.Author - }} meaning, it's looking for exactly 1 file, with a specific name.
[https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/][1] 
covers how to set-up a hugo multilingual - and there is SUPPOSED to be 1 Config file per site (which has it's own meaning in Hugo - see above page)
Point being, this is a theme issue, and I would suggest asking the theme creator to adapt edit.
My suggestion would be if the theme creator isn't helpful - would be to remove the dependency for the TOML file, and simply reference a headless bundle which has the author data, and as the theme has i18n, integrate the two (see above link) so that their is a headless bundle per language.